# why tf.train.batch returns only one batch of features?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a custom input function, as follows:

```
def my_input_fn():
  # parse a file and create a dictionary of features
  return features
```

This function is passed to `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator.predict` function as `input_fn` param. I want to pass my data in different batches. After searching, it seems that it's the responsibility of [`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch). So, editing my function as follow:

```
def my_input_fn():
  # parse a file and create a dictionary of features
  return tf.learn.batch(tensors=features, batch_size=100, enqueue_many=True)
```

The problem is that calling `predict(input_fn=my_input_fn)` returns the estimated results only for 100 examples in a batch. How can I design `my_input_fn` function to return all data in batches?

Answer (score 0):

For prospective readers:

- setting `as_iterable=True` solve the problem.